# Physical interface for ADSL Annex J

Tags: signal, network-interface

My mom’s ADSL line got upgraded from Annex B (bundled with ISDN) to Annex J (pure ADSL) a few months ago.

While doing maintenance at her house, I noticed that of the two wires coming into the house and going to the ADSL router, one was interrupted (i.e. the wire was broken), yet the router was connected to the Internet. I reconnected that wire, then disconnected the other one – the Internet connection stayed up.

Only when I disconnected both wires did the router lose its Internet connection – had it stayed online, I would have assumed the router is falling back to a mobile network whenever the ADSL link is interrupted (though I doubt this particular device is equipped for that).

But this particular behavior made me curious if I had misunderstood the physical layer of ADSL all the time. So far I have assumed that ADSL signaling is similar to POTS or the U bus on an ISDN line (i.e. the single wire pair going from the switching office to the NT), based on a voltage difference between two wires. But this would stop working if a single line were interrupted. The other explanation is that ADSL (at least Annex J) uses radio frequency electromagnetic waves for signaling, similar to a TV cable.

An Internet search did not provide any further clues on this. Any pointers?

Comment: "interrupted", by what? A disconnection, or some kind of seemingly-unnecessary hardware?

Comment: @Hearth The wire was broken, I have updated the question.

Comment: When you say "one of the wires", do you mean a single-conductor wire, or a multi-conductor cable?

Comment: There are two single-conductor wires coming into the house (probably a two-conductor cable, but for the most part inside the house it is just two conductors twisted together). So by “wire” I mean “longish, solid piece of conductive material with an insulating layer around it”.

Answer (score 0):

ADSL is AC coupled and thus can tolerate some forms of glavanic isolation.

The old "splitter" boxes put the DSL signal onto the existing (DC voltage when idle) analog/ISDN lines via capacitors. That means there was no DC connection between the "line" and the DSL equipment.

"One line disconnected" can work if some HF magic is present - signal quality might have been degraded.